# Turtle Onkey - Escape Key

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm using turtle.onkey, but I'm not sure what name corresponds to the escape key. I've tried 'escape' and 'esc', but neither of those seem to work. Can someone let me know what the proper name is? A link to a full list of key names would be even better.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the [mcve] that you had when trying your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Escape":

```
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(lambda: screen.bgcolor('blue'), "Escape")
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```